# Knuth's algorithm for solving MasterMind with 5 guesses

Tags: c#, algorithm

I read knuth's algorithm [in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29#Five-guess_algorithm) and I wonder about the 3rd step. If I understand correct for each option (even if not removed in step 2), we calculate how many possible guesses would have removed for every ffedback. for that step we take minimum. after, we find the maximum on the minimums and take the code the max belong to it. that will be our second guess. Im not sure what can be done next because,each time we dont change the max on the minimums (or what is the minimum). In addition, how can I implement this step in c# for example. How can I procceed and how can I implement that step? What does the minimum on the feedbacks really mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a constant collection of all possible outcomes, a collection of the remaining alternatives, and a method that can compute the outcome given a guess and a solution.

First, model the relevant domain objects:

```
public class Outcome
{
    public int White { get; set; }
    public int Black { get; set; }
}

public class Combination
{
    // however you like to model this
}
```

Then, create the method that checks the guess against the secret:

```
public static Outcome Check(Combination guess, Combination solution)
{
    // your implementation
}
```

Now the algorithm is as follows:

```
Outcome[] outcomes = new[] { new Outcome { White = 0, Black = 0 },
                             new Outcome { White = 1, Black = 0 },
                             // ... all other possibilities
                            };

// assume we have some list of combinations
int min = Integer.MaxValue;
Combination minCombination = null;
foreach (var guess in combinations)
{
    int max = 0;
    foreach (var outcome in outcomes)
    {
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var solution in combinations)
        {
            if (Check(guess, solution) == outcome)
                count++;
        }
        if (count > max)
            max = count;
    }
    if (max < min)
    {
        min = max;
        minCombination = guess;
    }
}
```

At the end of the loop, `minCombination` is your next guess.

**EDIT** I messed up min and max in the first version, that is fixed now. The inner count gives the number of remaining options, provided the chosen `combination` and the assumed `outcome`. We want the maximum over the outcomes (the worst possible result for the chosen `combination` is the one that leaves most options remaining). After that we want the minimum over the combinations (the best possible combination is the one that leaves least options remaining in the worst case).

If you like Linq, you could also write the algorithm as

```
combinations.MaxBy(guess =>
        outcomes.Min(outcome =>
                combinations.Count(solution => 
                        Check(guess, solution) == outcome)));
```

in which I used `MaxBy` from the [MoreLinq project](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

Comment: thanks but what is c in `check(combination,c)`?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis it's the variable of the lambda expression in count and represents the solution. In that line I count all the solutions that would lead to `outcome`. You could also write it as a foreach loop.

Comment: where did you define it and what do you mean by "the lambada expression"? by the way i can find here only the next guess but not the one after it, can I?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis I just updated the answer to use a foreach loop. The other version used Linq, you should look that up some time, it's really interesting, but maybe this version is easier to follow. You can just reuse this snippet over and over again to find the next guess. All you need to do is keep `combinations` up to date (those are the combinations that may still be the solution, based on the outcomes you received so far).

Comment: thanks. afer finding minCombination I play it and reduce combinations from alreday-reduced-combinationes array? if so: why do we need to find minimax evry step suppose it doesn't change between them?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis the "already-reduced-combinations array" is what I called `combinations` in above algorithm. That array changes in every step, so the minimax has also to be recomputed. What does not change is the outcome for a combination of guess and solution. You could precompute the result of all possible `Check` calls somewhere.  That might give the algorithm quite a speedup, but it's not necessary.